# Given formatTime method in JavaFX Ensemble Returning Wrong Time Format

Tags: java, javafx-8, media-player

I am trying to build a media player and taking help from [JavaFX Sample Ensemble.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) There is a method named `private String formatTime(Duration elapsed, Duration duration)` which returns correct duration if the media is less than an hour. The problem occurs when the media is greater than 60 minutes. The hour and minutes calculation is ok, where second is not.

For example, I have a movie which's duration is `02:06:42`. When I am opening this media, it shows duration `02:06:-7158`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation on that method is ok except the `durationSeconds` part line.

```
int intDuration = (int) Math.floor(duration.toSeconds());
int durationHours = intDuration / (60 * 60);
if (durationHours > 0)
{
    intDuration -= durationHours * 60 * 60;
}
int durationMinutes = intDuration / 60;
int durationSeconds = intDuration - durationHours * 60 * 60 - durationMinutes * 60;
```

Here, when `durationHours` is being calculated, `intDuration` is also being deducted on the if block. But at the last line, where second is being calculated, we are deducting `durationHours` again from `intDuration` which we already has deducted in the `if` block. That is why we are getting a big negative value for seconds when the duration is greater than an hour.

**Here is the solution-**

```
int durationSeconds = intDuration - durationMinutes * 60;
```

Just replacing last line with this line will solve the problem. Here we have to remove the hour reducing part `- durationHours * 60 * 60` which already been calculated in `if` block.